# List files based on modification times

Tags: ls, recursive, date-modified

How can I run the `ls` command with all its options and list all files in directories recursively and sort it based on last modification times?

ie
ls -lth on all files in directories recursively

Answer (score 1):

First, which flavor of unix are you using? Systems based on BSD will have a different option set for `ls` from System V.

Second, http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls lists a `-R` switch to force a recursive listing, and `-c` to base its sort on `ctime`, or modification time.

The trick is to verify that your flavor of *nix uses a version of `ls` that includes those switches.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a global sort, rather than a per-directory sort like you would get with `ls -Rlth`.

If the total number of files is not too large, this can be accomplished using the `find` command to gather the names and pass them to `ls` for sorting:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lth {} +
```

or alternatively

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lth
```

(On some older systems, the `find` command does not support either `-exec ... +` or `-print0`.  In that case you could use `-print` instead of `-print0` and omit `-0`, but then it will not work with file names containing spaces or other special characters.)

**Caveat:** If the number of files that you are sorting is large then there may be too many to list as arguments to a single `ls` command.  In that case `ls` will be called multiple times and the sorting will only be correct within each group of files.